# Not compile code blocks when publishing?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have many lines i just use for debugging and helpers. Is there a way i can mark these so they do not compile when publishing a project but still can use when running/debugging my program within Eclipse? Even better would be to mark a certain field as debug only and discard everything that has to do with that field completely when publishing.

I understand this might get one in trouble when using fields like that and using that in critical parts of the code. But i often find myself initializing a lot of debug fields then comment them out which results in errors down the line if i do not comment those out as well.

So is there some way to handle this in a better and more efficient way?

Comment: What kind of fields do you add for debug purposes?

Comment: @Steinar Counters, string, timers... etc. Currently i am displaying mouse position, world position and tile coordinates on screen. This is awesome for me and i might add more code to it so i can switch it on and off. I would then add much more of these things to help me out. But i have to comment everything out when i want to publish something.

Comment: Logging is the best and standard option as others have pointed. If you want to observe object and internal fields you could also use [Watch Expressions](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fexpressions%2Fref-addwatch.htm) while debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code inside an `if` statement that refers to a `final static boolean` constant in another class. An `if` statement like `if (DEBUG)` that effectively says `if (false)` (because  DEBUG is false) is not compiled by the Java compiler.

```
public class Debug {
    public final static boolean DEBUG = true; // or false
}

public class X {
    public m() {
        if (Debug.DEBUG) {
             // Do some timing or displaying mouse positions, or whatever.
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to verify that this works, you can use the `javap` disassembler: the compiler won't generate code if your DEBUG constant is `false`, but if DEBUG is `true` it will.

For further reference, the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#d5e19433) (linked) has a section on conditional compilation, "Example 13.4.9-2". This explains what I've described above.

Comment: This is an interesting approach but everything is still there after publishing. Also, if I have fields declared outside the loop they still count to memory.

Comment: No it's not, that's why it's called *"conditional compilation"*. When DEBUG equals `false`, it is *not there* after publishing.

Comment: Really, then this is the actual answer i am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the trace level of your favorite logger, e.g. log4j.

Comment: A bit more comprehensiveness is welcome. But I'll look into it.

Comment: See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/ The logger is controlled by an XML configuration file, and you can use *if (logger.isDebugEnabled())* or *if (logger.isTraceEnabled())* to control whatever statements you wish.

Comment: In my use of Log4J2, I've never had to explicitly check if the logger was in debug mode.  If it isn't, nothing gets written out when logging at that level.

Comment: @Makoto When you write _logger.debug_ or _logger.trace_, _log4j_ does it for you. I was referring to the case when you have **code** that you only want to execute while debugging. I am under the impression that this was the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Use a logging framework.

A logging framework exists to allow developers to write out important events to either the standard command line, to a file, or anywhere else they desire.  Java comes with a built-in (albeit primitive) logging framework:  `java.util.logging`.

Here's a sample of it in action.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("foo-logger");

logger.log(Level.INFO, "This is a log statement at a rather standard logging level - use when you want to log information out.");
logger.log(Level.WARNING, "This is a log statement at a rather moderate logging level - use when things warrant looking into but aren't mission critical.");
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "This is a log statement at a rather high logging level - use when an (often irrecoverable) error has occurred.");
```

If you use that, then you'll see something similiar to this in your terminal:

```
Aug 23, 2014 10:05:24 AM com.stackoverflow.sandbox.Formatting main
INFO: This is a log statement at a rather standard logging level - use when you want to log information out.
Aug 23, 2014 10:05:24 AM com.stackoverflow.sandbox.Formatting main
WARNING: This is a log statement at a rather moderate logging level - use when things warrant looking into but aren't mission critical.
Aug 23, 2014 10:05:24 AM com.stackoverflow.sandbox.Formatting main
SEVERE: This is a log statement at a rather high logging level - use when an (often irrecoverable) error has occurred.
```

Other frameworks such as [Log4J2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) are more intuitive as to what the levels mean, as well as offer simpler options to log out to wherever you desire.

Comment: Still not exactly what i was looking for but better then an if statement since that would be running when published anyway. This does not get compiled at all when export/publish my project if i understand it properly?

Comment: It does, but it doesn't impact much.  You can't really do conditional compilation in Java like you would in C; the other alternative being wrapping everything in a giant if block, which gets untenable.  Logging statements are more universal and widely accepted; if you only ever log things to a debug level or lower, you won't have any issues with someone reading those logs unless someone decides to log to that low of a level.

Comment: Yes, Java does have conditional compilation; see my answer below. (check the link to the JLS to verify)